# Finding normal vector to a plane

Tags: systems-of-equations, plane-geometry

> Find the equation of the plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that contains the points 
>   $v=(1, 2, 1)$, 
>   $w=(0, 1, 4)$, and
>   $q=(-1, -1, 0)$.

Equation of the plane is given by $ax+by+cz+d=0$ with normal vector $N=(a,b,c)$.

Let $t=w-v=(2,3,1)$ and $s=q-v=(1,2,4)$.

Then I calculate $q=N-v=(a+1,b+1,v)$ to get the orthogonal normal vector to $t$ and $s$.

And use $q\cdot t=0$ and $q\cdot s=0$.

I know this is wrong, and I should be using $N\cdot t=0$ and $N\cdot s=0$, but I don't understand why my logic is wrong. Isn't $q=N-v$ normal to the plane since $v$ is in the plane already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$q = N - v$ will not be normal to the plane. If N is normal to the plane, and v is a vector in the plane, then q is not normal unless v is zero. Consider a vector in a plane, then also a normal vector to that plane, the difference between the two will be a hypotenuse of a triangle connecting the end of one vector to the end of the normal vector, and that will not be normal since it's not the normal vector. If you want a vector normal to your plane, use the cross product with 2 vectors that are in your plane. Also, q is just a point on your plane, not a vector that coincides with your plane. If you want a vector that is in your plane, subtract one point in your plane from another. e.g. $v - w$.

Comment: Thanks that was extremely helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Your $t$ and $s$ are (should be) noncollinear vectors both parallel to the plane. Therefore you can take their cross-product to get a normal vector to the plane.

Also, your calculations of $t$ and $s$ are incorrect.

$$t=w-v=\langle-1,-1,3\rangle$$

$$s=q-v=\langle0,-1,-1\rangle$$